# Viewmodel list inside a remember{ mutableStateOf() } returns empty list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

So i have a "storeViewModel" which returns a store list that i want to use inside a lazyVerticalGrid
The thing is i tried putting the store list inside of a remember{ } function so it does survive recomposition, like this:

`val storeList by remember{ mutableStateOf(storeViewModel.list) }`

But it crashes when i run the app saying the function is returning an empty list

But when i declare it outside of the remember function like this:

`val storeList = storeViewModel.list`

it works like charm, but the order gets reset on every recomposition.
Im pretty sure it has something to do with delegation but i dont know exactly
Any suggestions what it could be?

Comment: You haven't showed any code that has anything to do with the ordering of the list.

Comment: U dont need to remember that list because its in view model, and also take look at mutableStateListOf()

Comment: Im trying to sort the list in reverse order everytime i click a button by doing this:
`storeViewModel = storeViewModel.reversed()` , and it works, but everytime recomposition gets triggered the order gets lost, that's why i wanted to use the remember{} function in the first place.
I also tried using a mutable list and then later filling that list using `storeViewModel.list.forEach{     mutableList.add(store)    }` , and also works, but sometimes the data doesn't get updated when list is in reverse order and i call the viewmodel again using storeViewModel.getStores() function @ianhanniballake